# Python multiprocessing debug

Tags: python, python-multiprocessing

I'm trying to get the hang of Python multiprocessing but my tests so far show sequential running instead of parallelism.

I tried this simple code:

multiprocessing.py:

```
import multiprocessing
import os


def proc1():
    os.system('python proc1.py')

def proc2():
    os.system('python proc2.py')

if __name__ == "__main__":
    p1 = multiprocessing.Process(target=proc1())
    p2 = multiprocessing.Process(target=proc2())
    p1.start()
    p2.start()
```

proc1.py:

```
import time
for i in range(0,5):
    print('process 1: ', i)
    time.sleep(0.5)
```

proc2.py:

```
import time
for i in range(0,5):
    print('process 2: ', i)
    time.sleep(0.5)
```

My understanding is that this *should* run parallel on different CPUs, however, the console output is always this:

```
process 1:  0
process 1:  1
process 1:  2
process 1:  3
process 1:  4
process 2:  0
process 2:  1
process 2:  2
process 2:  3
process 2:  4

Process finished with exit code 0
```

I think the two process outputs should be mixed and in varying order, depending on which core is 'faster'. Is this a limitation of Pycharm? Or am I doing something wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's a simple error in syntax. By doing

```
p1 = multiprocessing.Process(target=proc1())
```

you are saying that the target should be the output from proc1.
What you want is

```
p1 = multiprocessing.Process(target=proc1)
```

That way the target is the function proc1